# Python Selenium: No such file or directory when loading Firefox Profile

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-scraping

I'm trying to load a FirefoxProfile with selenium in Python, in order to make use of a persistent login cookie.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory='~/.mozilla/firefox/gu16idx8.default/')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

The frist line above throws this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.mozilla/firefox/gu16idx8.default/'
```

Even though the file does exist (verified with `cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/gu16idx8.default/`)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with *os.path.expanduser*

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(os.path.expanduser("~/.mozilla/firefox/gu16idx8.default/"))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```